# dcc.Store is expecting a list or a tuple

Tags: plotly-dash

I am getting the following error when trying to store a dictionary in dcc.Store. Doesn't it take a dict to store data?

```
dash._grouping.SchemaTypeValidationError: Schema: [<Output `user_status_check.data`>]
Path: ()
Expected type: (<class 'tuple'>, <class 'list'>)
Received value of type <class 'dict'>:
    {'user_status': [{'status': 'update', 'user_id': None, 'screen_name': 'mfa_russia'}]}
```

here's the layout

```
layout = html.Div([
    tw_user_navbar,
    popup_row,
    dcc.Store(id='user_data_values'),
    dcc.Store(id='user_status_check', storage_type='session', clear_data =True),
```

and the callback, not sure how helpful it would be in answering the question

```
@app.callback(
    [
    Output('user_status_check', 'data')
    ],
    [
        Input('screen_name', 'value'),
        Input('user_id', 'value'),
    ]
    )
def check_user_status(input_screen_name, input_user_id):
    if input_screen_name or input_user_id:
    # check if the user exists in the db
        from tw_mod.load.pg_db_functions import db_user_check
        user_in_db = db_user_check(screen_name=input_screen_name, user_id=input_user_id)
        # if so check if the user information is up-to-date
        if user_in_db:
            from tw_mod.tw_procssing import check_account_status
            account_status = check_account_status(user_id=input_user_id, screen_name=input_screen_name)
            if account_status:
                return {'user_status':[{'status':'no_update','user_id':input_user_id, 'screen_name':input_screen_name}]}
            else:
                return {'user_status':[{'status':'update','user_id':input_user_id, 
    else:
        from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
        raise PreventUpdate
```

Comment: what version of dash are you using?

Comment: I ended up getting some help through the Dash Community page. I had to take the Output out of the list

Comment: An alternative is to return a list, eg `return [{your dict}]`